# How to override button label in the Backoffice PCM?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am trying to override the label that is rendered for the "Save" and "Refresh" buttons in the Backoffice PCM. Once you open the editor of a product these two buttons are provided at the bottom of the screen. (screenshot)
I want to provide different labels for these buttons e.g. "Update" rather than "Save". I have changed many labels for other components and editors via locale*.properties files. I am just not able to identify for these ones.

I have tried looking for these labels by searching through many of the *.properties files in my extensions as well as the Hybris OOTB properties files. I cannot find where these are configured.

If someone knows where I need to look or how this can be done would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image: backoffice-pcm-btn]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties that define it are the following:

```
editorArea.save=Save
editorArea.reset=Refresh
```

Try to replace them with defining the following:

```
com.hybris.cockpitng.backoffice.defaultEditorArea.editorArea.save=New Save
com.hybris.cockpitng.backoffice.defaultEditorArea.editorArea.reset=New Refresh
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I had to include these properties in my backoffice extension e.g. myCustomBackoffice-backoffice-labels/labels_* rather than in the locales.